# Discord.py: Sending someone a message in a flask application

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, discord.py

I'm trying to set up a discord bot within a flask application. The way it works is that the user is logged in via discord's OAuth2 on a website and when he clicks a button, he should receive a message on discord. I don't know how to create a function, that executes `user.send("Hello")`, when clicking the button on the website.

```
import discord

async def dm(): 
    user = client.get_user(USERID)
    await user.send('Hello')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I want to import the dm() function in another flask file and execute it when the button is clicked. So I need a discord.py function, that sends a message to a specific user id, when its being called. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is not specifically about flask. In python in order to execute a function from another file you import it and call the function.

In your case you need a endpoint on your flask app like `/send/{userId}` and when user calls this endpoint(like having a button for this link) you call the function.

```
from yourfile import dm
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<user_id>')
def send_message(user_id):
    await dm(user_id)
```

Also you need to add user_id as an argument for `dm` function.

Comment: The problem is that the dm function is not working. I need a discord.py function, which sends a message automatically to an users id when its being called.

Comment: Well you need to pass the user_id to the function.

Comment: yes, I did that. The problem is that user returns nonetype. User only returns the right value when above the fuction is something with `@`. For example `@client.event`. And I can't use `@click.event`, because it is only being executed when something happens within discord

Comment: If you cannot get user id outside of discord environment then you may not be able to send messages to people at all!